# Dynamic selection of names on element in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Greetings to all Jquery wizards, Newbee here.

I need a valid syntax for selecting a dynamic name for a specific element using jquery.

My codes ATM*

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    var elemName = ('item' + j);
    $('*[name='(elemName)']').val('');
}
```

Just a head start, I cannot use `""` double quotes... It's a restriction to my work.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()) for concatenation. Also, `*` is not required.

```
$('[name=' + elemName + ']').val('');
//         ^          ^
```

OR, you can select **all** the elements whose `name` **starts with** `item` as follow, without `for` loop.

```
$('[name^="item"]').val('');
```

Comment: and remove the star, thats uselessy there

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript's getElementsByName method which accepts variable as a argument like Below,

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
var elemName = ('item' + j);
 $(document.getElementsByName(elemName)).val('');
}
```